# If spacetime is emergent, are strings and branes in String/M-Theory also emergent?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, string-theory

Many physicists including string theorists say that spacetime is emergent from something more fundamental. String theory says strings and branes are fundamental, or in the case of M-Theory, membranes are fundamental. If spacetime is not fundamental but emergent, then are strings/branes still fundamental or are they excited states of some underlying field or something else?